# Java error <identifier> expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am currently working on a Poker java game exercise, and I get this ugly error which I'm not being able to understand. It must be some kind of syntax error since the compiler throws 100 of those. But I just don't know where the error is??

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Poker
{
    private Card[] deck;
    private Card[] hand;
    private int currentCard;
    private int numbers[], triples, couples;
    private String faces[], suits[];

    private boolean flushOnHand, fourOfAKind, isStraight;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52;

    private static final Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    Poker()
    {
        faces = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
            "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        suits = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };

        numbers = new int[ 13 ];

        deck = new Card[ NUMBER_OF_CARDS ];

        triples = 0; // right here's where the compiler starts complaining
        couples = 0;
            ...
```

though I am not able to spot any syntax error?

Btw, the `Card` is a separate class.

Comment: Remove lines until the error goes away. Then you know what was causing it. -1 and "Too Localized" for not providing a minimal case (following the above technique, if needed). Hint: try removing the first 2 "lines" of the constructor. Array initialization via a plain `{..}` is a special declaration-only construct.

Comment: What compiler are you using that it doesn't give you an error on the `faces = {` line?  That's where my compiler gives an error.

Comment: I get an error `Array constants can only be used in initializers` on both the `faces =` and `suits =` lines.  I'm using Java 7.  What error were you getting?

Comment: @ErickRobertson - The java compiler gives an error on `faces = {`, but, at least in Java 6, it also gives a spurious error on the line OP indicates. When the `faces` and `suits` assignments are fixed, the error about "identifier expected" also goes away.

Comment: @TedHopp I don't get any error on the `triples =` line with Java 7.  But I'm curious how you know what errors OP's compiler is throwing?

Comment: @ErickRobertson - I don't know what OP's compiler is reporting, but that's what my compiler does. My guess is that OP is using the same thing. :)

Comment: My compiler reported: error <identifier> expected at the `triples = 0`

Comment: The lesson is: fix the first error first. Other errors may then simply go away on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why the variable `triples` can't be assigned where you are indicating the error.

However, you need to assign the String arrays like so:

```
faces = new String[] { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
         "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
suits = new String[] { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
```

Comment: You can only declare then without the `String[]` in the variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

**Your syntax for initializing the array values is incorrect.**

I'm not sure why the compiler is waiting an additional four lines before it starts complaining, but your array declaration is invalid several lines above.

```
    faces = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    suits = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
```

Should be like this...

```
    faces = new String[] { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    suits = new String[] { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
```

You can only use the first structure if you are initializing it on the same line you declare it, like this:

```
private String faces[] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
private String suits[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise that an answer has already been accepted here but I wanted to point out that it's easier to initialise your variables at their point of declaration if they don't rely on any parameters of the constructor, i.e.

```
public class Poker
{
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52;
    private Card[] deck = new Card[ NUMBER_OF_CARDS ];
    private int numbers[] = new int[ 13 ]
    private int triples = 0;
    private int couples = 0;
    private String faces[] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
                               "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    private String suits[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
```

etc.